# Sliding order in bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using bootstrap carousel to display five images...and i disabled the sliding while calling the carousel and my code is like this

```
     <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
         <div class="active item">item1</div>
         <div class="item">item2</div>
         <div class="item">item3</div>
         <div class="item">item4</div>
         <div class="item">item5</div>
     </div>

     <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">></a>
     <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><</a>
</div>
```

and i called the carousel like this

```
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval:false
     });
```

But the problem is while sliding  the elements displayed in the order

```
    item,item3,item5,item2,item4
```

What is the problem in this why it is not displayed in the correct order and how can I overcome this..

**Additional information:**

If i give active in item2 means the order is like this item2,item4,item,item3,item5

Comment: likely a CSS problem - or a bug

Comment: As a very cursory example, this seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/rb5FH/

Comment: A possible reason for this behaviour could be that you have more than one carrousel on the page at the same time.